# Ubuntu on smart tv

Tags: usb, samsung, smart

Is there anyway for Ubuntu to run on a Samsung Smart TV? At least on a USB? I personally don't like the smart hub that much and would like to watch cable and browse Ubuntu on my TV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to install and run Ubuntu on a Samsung Smart TV.

What we can do however is to attach a small dedicated Ubuntu computer with an HDMI interface to the TV. This could be any box ranging from a tiny Raspberry Pi box to a full blown media PC.

In our home we built an own Ubuntu PC based on a cheap mini-ITX board with integrated CPU/GPU. This box is more than suitable for occasional browsing but is mostly used for audio and video streaming of media stored on our Ubuntu desktop in the same network.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to gain root access with [SamyGo](http://forum.samygo.tv/viewtopic.php?t=6239) widget through hole in Skype client. When you do this, it's no problem to install Ubuntu Core.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to run Linux for ARM with a sd card or usb in some system :

https://forum.armbian.com/forum/24-tv-boxes/

(image to download in the sticky threads)

hard reset your box/tv to reboot in linux.